# How to Fix sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:

Tags: java, exception, resttemplate, pkix

I am hitting one URL from where XML is supposed to come as a response.
 When I hit the URL From browser I can see the XML. Same thing I want to acchive with RestTemplate.

```
   UriComponents uriComponents = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(ptcURL).queryParams(params).build();
                URL ptcACKPostURL = new URL(uriComponents.toUriString());
                LOG.info("### URL Contructed for PTC  Acknowledgement ###");
                LOG.info(ptcACKPostURL.toString());
                String repsonseFromPtc = restTemplateForPTC.postForObject(ptcACKPostURL.toString(), HttpMethod.POST, String.class);
```

When I print the URL at `LOG.info(ptcACKPostURL.toString());` I get exact url which I want to hit.

But I am getting

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://example.com": sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target;
 nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:607) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:557) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:357) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at com.jci.plmacknowledgement.dao.PLMACKMSDaoImpl.readPayloadTableEntityList(PLMACKMSDaoImpl.java:90) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.jci.plmacknowledgement.services.PLMACKMSServiceImpl.readPayloadTableEntityList(PLMACKMSServiceImpl.java:21) [classes/:na]
        at com.jci.plmacknowledgement.PLMACKMSApplication.sendAcknowledgementToPTC(PLMACKMSApplication.java:74) [classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_66]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_66]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_66]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_66]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_66]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_66]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_66]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:80) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:596) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
```

Comment: @JasonC : Yes, My URL is proper URL Which consists of username and password which I can't post here that's why i just modified URL as an example.